# How to send HTTP SOAP request to local Sonos device with NodeMCU?

Tags: http, post, soap, nodemcu, sonos

How do I send a simple HTTP POST/GET SOAP request to my Sonos loudspeaker in Lua?

I have tried simple HTTP POST and GET requests with success, but I do not know where to start with SOAP requests.

Note: I am a newbie at this. I have never worked with a NodeMCU before nor have I programmed in Lua. I have experience in other languages though.

I know how to do it in C#, Java and PHP.

This works in Postman:

HTTP Headers:

```
SOAPAction:urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause
Content-Type:text/xml; charset="utf-8"
Host:192.168.0.10:1400
```

BODY:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:Pause xmlns:u="urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1"><InstanceID>0</InstanceID></u:Pause></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

What I did is this and it does not work:

```
        sendRequest("192.168.0.10")
function sendRequest(url)
    print("Sending request to Sonos Playbar...")
    sk = net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
    sk:on("receive", function(sck, c) print(c) end )
    sk:on("connection", function(sck, c)

        print("\r\n\r\n\r\n")

        -- HTTP 405: Method not allowed
        -- sck:send("POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "..url..":1400\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")

        -- HTTP 500, UPnP 402: Invalid arguments
        -- sck:send("POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "..url..":1400\r\nSOAPAction:urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")


        local content = nil;
    content = "POST /MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control\r\n"
    content = content.."Host:192.168.0.10:1400\r\n"
    content = content.."Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n"
    content = content.."SOAPAction:urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause\r\n"
    content = content.."\r\n"

    -- SOAP Body
    content = content.."<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
    content = content.." s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
    content = content.."<s:Body>"
    content = content.."<u:Pause xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1\">"
    content = content.."<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>"
    content = content.."</u:Pause>"
    content = content.."</s:Body>"
    content = content.."</s:Envelope>"
    -- SOAP Body End

        print(content.."\r\n\r\n\r\n")

        sck:send(content);
    end)
    sk:connect(1400, url)
end
```

I am getting this response of my Sonos player:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
CONTENT-LENGTH: 347
CONTENT-TYPE: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
EXT: 
Server: Linux UPnP/1.0 Sonos/34.16-37101 (ZPS9)
Connection: close

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
                <faultstring>UPnPError</faultstring>
                    <detail>
                        <UPnPError xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:control-1-0">
                            <errorCode>401</errorCode>
                        </UPnPError>
                    </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong? I copied and paste the text, basically. Maybe it is the order of headers? Maybe I am declaring the headers wrong or something?

Comment: Can you link to the Sonos Api docs?

Comment: Here is the link to the Sonos Api docs, but I rather just send a plain SOAP request to my local Sonos equipment, because that also works in other programming languages (C#, Java, PHP) and setting up the API is quite a road to walk... musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=docs

Comment: Can you get the requests to work using an API tool like Postman (separate from your IoT stack)?  Thats the first step.

Comment: Just looking around briefly, I don't see you sending the POST body with XML in it. I think that is required for it to work. SOAP is an XML based protocol. E.g. http://www.hirahim.com/blog/2012/04/29/dissecting-the-sonos-controller/

Comment: Adam B Correct. Now I have copied the SOAP Body from my C# application (which works fine), but it still gives me the error above. It works using Postman. When I copy and paste the contents from Postman to ESplorer (IDE for NodeMCU), it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I have it working! Below is the code to get it working:

```
sendRequest("192.168.0.10")
function sendRequest(url)
    print("Sending request to Sonos Playbar...")
    local content = nil;
    content = "";
    -- SOAP Body
    content = content.."<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
    content = content.." s:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\">"
    content = content.."<s:Body>"
    content = content.."<u:Pause xmlns:u=\"urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1\">"
    content = content.."<InstanceID>0</InstanceID>"
    content = content.."</u:Pause>"
    content = content.."</s:Body>"
    content = content.."</s:Envelope>"
    -- SOAP Body End

    http.post("http://"..url..":1400/MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control",
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"\r\n'..
        'Host:'..url..':1400\r\n'..
        'SOAPAction:urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause\r\n',
        content, function(code, data)
            if(code < 0) then
                print("HTTP request failed with code "..code)
            else
                print(code, data)
            end
        end)
end
```

Comment: Looks exactly like what I suggested when you were still using the net module. Also note that you don't need the `Host` HTTP header with the HTTP module. It generates that automatically based on the URL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a Sonos device to play with. Thus, this ain't a *confirmed* answer.

The string in your `content` variable is not a valid HTTP request. Sonos doesn't understand it as the [error code 401 means "invalid action"](https://github.com/SoCo/SoCo/blob/master/soco/services.py#L145).

You need the separate HTTP headers with `\r\n`. An extra `\r\n` needs to be placed right before the HTTP body. Therefore, I'd expect that your `content` should be:

```
"POST http://192.168.0.10:1400/MediaRenderer/AVTransport/Control\r\n
SOAPAction:urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:AVTransport:1#Pause\r\n
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n
Host:192.168.0.10:1400\r\n\r\n
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xml......"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does not work either

Comment: Don't take it personal but I now have certain doubts about the correctness of some of the statements in your post. You apparently updated the code in the post with the input I gave here. If the original code had been copy-pasted here why would you have had to later alter it?

Comment: In any case I'd also try sending this HTTP POST with the [`http` module](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/http/).

Comment: Hi Marcel, thanks for your response. The reason I alter(ed) the code was because I was still experimenting with it and I did not want anybody saying things that are wrong in the code, that I already tried. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I am certainly going to try it with the HTTP module